# Inpage urdu to unicode Urdu converter

Tags: php, unicode, converters

Inpage is an Urdu software with which we can write Urdu. I found [a website](http://www.urdu.ca) which provides the feature to convert Inpage Urdu Text to Unicode Urdu found [here](http://www.urdu.ca/convert).

I want that functionality in PHP. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you can describe what this conversion process entails, for those not in the know?

Answer (score 6):

There is an Open source Inpage Urdu to Unicode Urdu Converter `Pak Inpage To Unicode Converter`, it was developed in Vb.net, but you can get the clue.
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2700846/_InPageConverter.zip

To Start:

1. Copy Inpage text in textbox.
2. Bring this text in Php.
3. Convert text into Byte Array.

   `for($i = 0; $i < strlen($inpage_data); ++$i) 
   {`

   ```
   $inp_code = ord($inpage_data[$i]);

   if ($inp_code == 128)
    {
        $unicode_urdu = $unicode_urdu . 'ب';
    }
   ```

   `}
   echo $unicode_urdu;
   ?>`

Every word in Inpage has unique code like, Alif = 129, Bay = 128, Pay = 146.

now convert inpage text to unicode Urdu accordingly in loop.

Comment: Brother Zeeshan where can we find the list of that codes? i searched alot

Comment: @Moxet Khan It is very easy indeed, you can write "Alif" to "Yeh" in Inpage with space between each alphabet, and then copy and paste that text in variable like $inpage_data = "........";. Now loop as above and print $inp_code to see codes.

Comment: Yes dear i tried like this but there were some extra binary like 4, 32. Let me try again.. Thank you :)

Comment: Kindly send me the list if you have.

Comment: I have ported this to javascript and an online demo is available here: http://nehaljwani.github.io/inPageToUnicode/

Comment: link broken 404 @NehalJWani

Comment: broken link @NehalJWani and your dropbox link is also broken

Answer (score 0):

Though its an old question but i would like to answer it so that it would help others who are still looking for the solution

```
Converter converter;
std::wstring UrduUnicodeText = converter.inpageToUnicode(InpageText);
std::wstring InpageText = converter.unicodeToInpage(UrduUnicodeText);
```

Check [this](https://github.com/umer0586/unicode-inpage-converter) source code at **Github**

Comment: inpage to unicode not properly working. Some symbols are not converting when they are combined.

Comment: @Khurram can you please give sample text your are talking about. Make sure your keyboard is set to "ENG" while copying converted text

Comment: I am trying implement this in JS. Facing problem when trying to convert byte to hex, have no idea how conversion occurs. I am following this guy https://github.com/ltrc/inPageToUnicode But I want to copy Inpage text and put into textbox the convet to unicode without uploading file. kindly help me to understand basic logic.

Comment: I saw your code what i understand you are also mapping hex but in different way also your code is in cpp

Comment: @Khurram Convertion logic is straight forward take an example of Unicode Urdu letter  ط (\u0637) which is represented as (\u0004\u2013) in Inpage, so you have to map \u0004\u2013 to u0637 while converting from Inpage to Urdu unicode. I don't know what logic the guy github.com/ltrc/inPageToUnicode  is using.

Comment: Yes the code is in c++ but i think c++ code can be called by PHP when cpp file in compiled as dll

Comment: mapping is not issue for me. But the problem is how can I get the code of Inpage from data or string. I'm a JS developer.

Comment: I'm interested in your solution output is OK. But I want to port this in JS, Only problem is getting letter's code. code are byte or hex value.

Comment: @Khurram To get code for Inpage or Urdu letter/string, paste letter/string at this link https://r12a.github.io/app-conversion/

Comment: bro thanks for help, I am looking at this link and will try to fix my issue now.